# How to insert arbitrary html on a gridview footer

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

Hello i have a gridview generated automatically by visual studio with boundfields like this:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    DataKeyNames="ID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" Width="849px" 
    ShowFooter="True">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="CarName" HeaderText="Car" 
            SortExpression="CarName"  />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Color" HeaderText="Color" SortExpression="Color" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

I want to insert a textbox on the footer of those boundfields, so the user can input new data. I've seen everywhere only examples with templatefield but no with boundfields is this possible?

I don't want to use templatefield as i dont know how to bind the data coming from the sql server to them. I tried using its text property, but the textbox there as html are not picked up by the compiler and raise exceptions if i tried to access them in the aspx.cs file.

It would be ok anyway to add a static row to the gridview i just want my textboxes aligned in with the columns.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/How_to_create_custom_boun.aspx see if this helps

Answer (score 1):

You could indeed use [TemplateFields](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb288032.aspx).
A [second possibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb310553.aspx) is to add a 'RowDataBound' event handler:

```
    public virtual void RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRow row)
    {
        if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
        }
        else if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer && ShowFooter)
        {
        }
        else if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
        {
            // here you need to be
            //row.Cells[0].Controls.Add(.....)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should learn  TemplateFields in gridview [Tutorial 12: Using TemplateFields in the GridView Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb288032.aspx)

[How to add a new row in the GridView control by using the GridView Footer Template](http://www.vkinfotek.com/gridview/gridview-footertemplate.html)

Comment: i tried the template field way and it works, but adding a textbox inside a footertemplate (that lives inside templatefield) produces the same error, if i try to access it with code in aspx.cs (textbox.text) the compiler complains that the textbox does not exist, is there anyway to prevent this?

Comment: That will probably be a 'timing' issue. I guess you are trying to retrieve that textbox, before the control is actually added to the controls collection.  
Try to override the 'RowDataBound' as I proposed. There you should be able to talk to that textbox.